# Splitting EEG Signal into Frequency Bands

Tags: matlab, frequency, frequency-analysis

I am currently working to create a program in MATLAB that splits an EEG signal into different frequency bands for evaluation of seizures. My question is, how do I split an EEG signal, without filters, into different frequency bands. For example, the delta waves (0-4 Hz), theta waves (4-7 Hz), etc. Currently, all I have is reading in to channel the EEG signal is located and an fft of the signal to transform it into the frequency domain. I need to split this signal into different frequency bands for evaluation. I['m thinking of possibly using the euclidean distance of the fft for the different frequency ranges but am unsure as to how to actually accomplish this. Any comment is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is probably time-frequency analysis, where you get how much energy there was for each frequency band per time window. Let's say you have spikes with a 40Hz frequency. You will only see them in fft if it is computed for the short time around the spikes, and not by using fft for the whole signal. Matlab's [spectrogram](https://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) does that, time-frequency analysis with short-time Fourier transform. Once you get Fourier transform per time window, you can add or average the absolute signal across the frequencies of interest. But there is a whole science to it - which wavelets to use, how many cycles per frequency, you may want to use some designated EEG tools by [FieldTrip](http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/workshop/oslo2019/timefrequency/) (if you prefer scripts) or [EEGLab](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/Chapter_11:_Time/Frequency_decomposition) (if you prefer GUI).

Answer (score 0):

1.if you want to split EEG into different frequency bands, you can use the wavelet method. by wavelet decomposition according to Fs(frequency sampling of data), you can have different frequency bands like alpha, beta, theta, and gamma by defining some level of wavelet...

2.if you want to analyze a particular frequency in signal(just one frequency in signal, no a band of signal), you can use the Empirical mode decomposition(EMD) method.

3.You can use this syntax to extract famous bands (Alpha, beta, theta...) from EEG

p = bandpower(x,fs,freqrange)

example: p=bandpower(myEEG_channel,512,[0 4]) in this example we calculate Delta band power from a channel of my EEG signal with fs=512 Hz.